# how can we set multiple local notification ? I

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on local notification,I want to fire multiple notifications at a same time for monday ,tuesday etc. like that,please give me any idea for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

or

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

If you want to repeat a local notification pls go through this

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html

All information must be provided when you schedule a local notification